# How to Iterate over an XML Element result set from a Linq Query

Tags: xml, linq

This is my idea for the code (can the Linq query populate the dictionary object directly?).

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(data.xml);
string Element = "KeyNode";
string SearchString = "Dominion";
Dictionary<string, string> QueryData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var query = from child in doc.Descendants(Element)
            where SearchString == child.Value
            select pn.Parent.Elements();


foreach(XElement x in query)
{
    QueryData.Add(x.Name.ToString(),x.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this to create the dictionary:

```
var queryData = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Name.ToString(), x => x.Value);
```

However, that's only safe if you know your XML doesn't have any duplicate names. If it might have duplicate names, you may want to get a distinct list in your query, or else investigate [`ToLookup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) as an alternative to `ToDictionary()`.

Also, your code is storing the tag name as the dictionary key. If that's what you need, then great. But if you actually need the value of a tag attribute or something like that, then you'll need to change your code.

**Update**

I think I see what the problem is. You never actually stated what your difficulty in iterating the results is, but I think this might be it:

The `Elements()` method returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. That means that the type of your `query` variable is actually `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`. If you want to flatten that down to a single list of all the elements, here's how:

```
var flattened = query.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: thanks for the dictionary part but to try it I need to iterate the initial result.

Comment: That's it! the rebels are there and I'm sure Skywalker is with them!

Thanks a lot, the flattening did the trick. If you can please explain why my resultset yielded nested ienumerables?

Comment: Pretend your select statement was `select child.Name.ToString()`. You'd get an `IEnumerable<string>`. Your real select statement returns a sequence of elements (all the parent's children). Since the end result of a query is a sequence of the values produced by each call to the select statement, and each select statement returns a sequence of elements, you end up with a sequence of a sequence of elements.